# How to clone a php spreadsheet template without data?

Tags: php, spreadsheet

I have added a xlsx template loaded.

```
    $Reader = new PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
    $spreadsheet = $Reader->load($template_path);
```

I would like to clone it after I have filled it with data.

**PhpSpreadsheet** Documentation explains how to clone a template with data, but I only need the template in a new sheet without data.

Comment: Well... why wouldn't you just clone the template instead of the sheet that's filled out?

Comment: because first I have to fill the template with data and then depending on some conditions I have to add the template in a new sheet.

Comment: Clone the empty template before it's filled. Then, after filling, delete the new sheet if it's not required depending on the conditions